# Getting variables outside an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS and jQ. I have this code:

```
 function CalculatePrice() {
  var a, b, c;
 if($(radiobtn1).is(':checked')) {
    a = "0";
      alert(a);
 }
 if($(radiobtn2).is(':checked')) {
    a = "1";
      alert(a);
 }
 if($(radiobtn3).is(':checked')) {
    a = "0";
      alert(a);
 }


 if($(radiobtn4).is(':checked')) {
    b = "350";
      alert(b);
 }
 if($(radiobtn5).is(':checked')) {
    b = "450";
      alert(b);
 }
 if($ (radiobtn6).is(':checked')) {
    b= "0";
      alert(b);
 }
 //This is what i'm asking about:
  alert(a);
}
```

The last alert  (alert(a);) doesn't run.  Im guessing this has something to do with variable scope but not sure. How do I get to access the variables set in the if statements?

Thanks!

Comment: i can't help but think there is a more efficient way of doing this. Perhaps `var b = $('[type=radio]:checked').val()`

Comment: If you open the browser's dev tools (usually that's F12, if not look in the menus) and go to the Console tab, what error(s) do you see? Provided all of those `radiobtnX` variables exist, you should see the final alert unless an error is occurring.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is not the problem since `$(x)` still returns a jQuery object if it finds no match for the selector `x`

Comment: are the radiobtn1, 2, 3, etc defined somewhere in the code? or are they  ids or classes?

Answer (score 0):

change the ifs to else if statements and this will work.

Comment: I can't see how that will help. The `alert()` in question is outside the `if` blocks.

Comment: @KriiV: That suggests that one of your later `radiobtnX` variables doesn't exist and you're getting an error (see comment on question). The above would have the *side effect* of avoiding the error in some conditions, but isn't a solution. (That said, when you're repeatedly assigning to a single variable in a series of conditions, `else if` is usually want you want.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would work:

```
function CalculatePrice() {
  var a, b, c;
 if($('#radiobtn1').is(':checked')) {
    a = "0";
      alert(a);
 }
 if($('#radiobtn2').is(':checked')) {
    a = "1";
      alert(a);
 }
 if($('#radiobtn3').is(':checked')) {
    a = "0";
      alert(a);
 }


 if($('#radiobtn4').is(':checked')) {
    b = "350";
      alert(b);
 }
 if($('#radiobtn5').is(':checked')) {
    b = "450";
      alert(b);
 }
 if($ ('#radiobtn6').is(':checked')) {
    b= "0";
      alert(b);
 }
 //This is what i'm asking about:
  alert(a);
}
```

**The Problem:**

you have to select the ids as e.g. `$('#radiobtn1')`